# JSON response returning null array

Tags: javascript, json

Please help i have been trying from 1 hours and not able to get whats wrong

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01">Result<br/></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book/2279690981";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out =  arr[i].ID + arr[i].Title + arr[i].Description;
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to fetch details from http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book/2279690981 but it show only empty array being returned. What changes are required ?

Modification
I added [ ] on JSON object and it worked .. Please can someone explain me.

Thank in advance :)

Comment: I would highly recommend using one of the libraries that simplifies ajax calls. However, in this case: are you doing jsonp? CORS? How are you getting to a different server? Or is `it-ebook-api.info` your server?

Comment: Different server. However i just figured out include [ ] at json object side is making it run

Comment: It looks like your endpoint returns an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response does not contain an array, so the for loop is not needed and this should get you the result you are looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01">Result<br/></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book/2279690981";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myresponse = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myresponse);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
        out =  "<p>" + response.ID + response.Title + response.Description + "<p>"; 
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
```

If you use the full listing available from http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/php, then you need the for loop to go through the array like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01">Result<br/></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myresponse = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myresponse.Books);
    }
}

function myFunction(Books) {
    var out = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < Books.length; i++) {
      out += "<p>ID: " + Books[i].ID + "</p>" + "<p>Title: " + Books[i].Title + "</p>" + "<p>Description: " + Books[i].Description + "</p>"
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And to make it slightly more elegant, you could have a function that adds the book and if you get only one book you can call it directly from the onreadystatechange, and if you have the full listing, then you can loop it through, but still use the same function. So something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01">Result<br/></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttpo.responseText);
        if (response.Books) { // If the response object has Books array, we pass it to the parseBooks functoin to add them all one by one.
          parseBooks(response.Books)
        } else {
          addBook(response); // If there is no Books array, we assume that there is only one book and add it to the list with addBook function.
        }
    }
}

function addBook (Book) {
  var text = document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML;
  var body = "<p>ID: " + Book.ID + "</p><p>Title: " + Book.Title + "</p><p>Description: " + Book.Description + "</p>";

  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = text + body; // Append the innerHTML with the new Book.
}

function parseBooks(Books) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Books.length; i++) {
      addBook(Books[i]) // Add all books in the array one by one
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works. but now how will i handle this http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/php

Comment: I edited the answer to cover this one also. So when you call the /v1/search/php and get the full listing, then you can access the Books array in the response and in myFunction loop through it and create the required elements for each book. If you call just the specific book, then you won't get the Books array but a single object instead.

Comment: It should be better to keep one function for both array and straight object and the iterate through through the array calling the function.

Comment: @tmarwen True. Modified the answer still with slightly more clean way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You JSON feed is just a simple object and not an Array of objects. *Note the opening curly braces in the returned feed: **{}***

You should then change your `myFunction` function so it goes through an object and not an array just by removing the `for` loop:

```js
function myFunction(obj) {
    var out = "",
    id01 = document.getElementById("id01");
    out =  obj.ID + obj.Title + obj.Description;
    id01.innerHTML = id01.innerHTML + out;
}
```

### Edit:

You can use the same function then inside a for loop when you have to parse an Array of Objects.

Taking as a feed the JSON returned from *http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/php*, you can retrieve the `Books` value and then loop through it:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book/2279690981";
var url2 = "http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var rslt = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        console.log(rslt);
        var books = rslt.Books;
        for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
        {
            myFunction(books[i]);
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url2, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works. but now how will i handle this it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/php

Comment: Please take a look at the Edit with * it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/php* as URL.